# Get first firebase child without key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the first child of a firebase object. My ref looks like this:

```
var sitesToVisitRef = firebase.database().ref('sitesToVisit')
```

I know the ref works because I can write to it. My data structure can look like this:

```
sitesToVisit:
  arstechnica-com:
    url: "https://arstechnica.com"
```

However, I don't know the key (arstechnica-com), but I need to get the url.

I am trying to with this code:

```
var nextUrl;
sitesToVisitRef.limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("snapshot key" + snapshot.key);
    console.log("snapshot.val.url = " + snapshot.val().url);
    console.log("snapshot.val" + snapshot.val());
      nextUrl = snapshot.val().url;
    }
  });
```

But snapshot.key logs as "sitesToVisit", not "arstechnica-com".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Um...if you're getting sitesToVisit through that, don't you just add `.child()` to get arstechnica-com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nextUrl;
sitesToVisitRef.limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    for(var key in snapshot.val()){
        console.log("snapshot key" + key);
        console.log("snapshot.val.url = " + snapshot.val()[key].url);
        console.log("snapshot.val" + snapshot.val()[key]);
        nextUrl = snapshot.val()[key].url;
    }
  });
```

What you have in `snapshot` is an array with all the childs in `sitesToVisit`, since you used `limitToFirst(1)` it's only the forst one, but it still is an array so you need to iterate over that array to get the key of each child.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!